# Left Ellipsis Overflow on IE/Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

```css
.left-ellipsis {
  text-align: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: rtl;
}

.left-ellipsis span {}


/* Media query for IE only. */

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
(-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  .left-ellipsis span {}
}
```

```html
<strong>With overflowing content</strong>
<br>
<i>Expected to see <strong>1 0002 0003 0004 0005 end</strong></i>
<div style="border: 1px solid #666; width: 200px; padding: 5px;">
  <div class="left-ellipsis">
    <span dir="ltr">123 456 789 0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 end</span>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<strong>Without overflowing content</strong>
<br>
<i>Expected to see <strong>0002 0003 0004 0005 end</strong> without ...</i>
<div style="border: 1px solid #666; width: 200px; padding: 5px;">
  <div class="left-ellipsis">
    <span dir="ltr">0002 0003 0004 0005 end</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Issue**: We want to show an ellipsis on our overflowing text on the left side of the div.

**Problem**: The solution works well in Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't work correctly in IE or Edge.  The ellipsis is shown on the left side correctly, but the data is chopped from the right, not from the left.

[image: IE problem]

**Attempts**:

- I have tried to add a 'float:right' to the span, which then makes
  IE/Edge show the correct data, but the ellipsis goes away entirely.
- We have gotten to this point by scouring SO for the 'direction' solution. It works with good browsers it seems.

Any help is greatly appreciated. This has been quite the challenge.

**Edit:** Here's a plunker where people can try things:
https://plnkr.co/edit/AWyzZLhnLbt4DStnU5hW?p=preview

Attempting to use the code provided by the article that @ovokuro posted, we get chrome to display this, which is no good either.:

[image: doesnt work either]

Comment: @jaunt Why did you remove my plunker? Are plunkers not allowed on SO?

Comment: They are but it's best to use a snippet if you can because it makes it much easier to copy into answers, didn't think there was much purpose to having a link too - add it back if you want :)

Comment: This article might have some advice: https://hugogiraudel.com/2014/12/16/css-riddle-reverse-ellipsis/

Comment: are you willing to add some JS into this?

Comment: @andi I suppose we sure could.  No JS has been used so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something to try that uses JS.  I don't have IE to test on, but hopefully it'll give you some logic to go on either way.  The basic idea is to test the widths of the content and its container, while removing one character at a time to see when it fits. (I used jQuery just because it's faster for me, but you certainly don't need it.)

```js
$('.left-ellipsis').each(function() {
 var $span = $(this).find('span');
 if ($span.width() > $(this).width()) {
  $span.addClass('ellipsis');
  while ($span.width() > $(this).width()) {
   $span.text($span.text().substr(1));
  }
 }
});
```

```css
.left-ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-ellipsis span {
 white-space:nowrap;
}

.left-ellipsis span.ellipsis {
 float:right;
}

.left-ellipsis span.ellipsis:before {
 content:"...";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>With overflowing content</strong><br>
<i>Expected to see <strong>1 0002 0003 0004 0005 end</strong></i>
<div class="left-ellipsis" style="border: 1px solid #666; width: 200px; padding:5px;">
 <span>123 456 789 0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 end</span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<strong>Without overflowing content</strong><br>
<i>Expected to see <strong>0002 0003 0004 0005 end</strong> without ...</i>
<div class="left-ellipsis" style="border: 1px solid #666; width: 200px; padding: 5px;">
 <span>0002 0003 0004 0005 end</span>
</div>
```

Comment: +1.  It looks like it does work on IE.  Is there an easy way we could get the text to left-justify when the content does not overflow?

Comment: I think you should just be able to move the `float:right` to `span.ellipsis` which is only used in an overflow situation.

Comment: Thanks @andi.  There's one more case here, and that's to update the ellipsis when the screen's width is changed.  I added a plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/rolCM3HD0Cw3LBVKEU4c?p=preview

Comment: ah...  in that case, you would first need to store the original text in a data attribute (since the code above deletes characters).  Then, in a resize handler, first set the text back to the original text, remove the class `ellipsis` if it was added before, then re-run the function above.

Comment: made some changes to the plunkr to show you: https://plnkr.co/edit/rtsEbTF0shmFQAm2l2yL?p=preview

Comment: Thanks so much. I just ran this in all 3 major browsers and things are working as expected.  On a side note - you might consider pushing this up to NPM. I don't think there are any nice ellipsis tools that allow left-justification.